# javascript filter return returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my reactJS application I want to return the lowest level elements. It is possible for elements to be in the same level (y coordinate). I only want to keep the lowest ones.

```
[ a, b, c  --> (same level - same y-coordinate)
  d, e     --> (same level - same y-coordinate)
  f, g, h] --> (same level - same y-coordinate)
```

So I want to be able to filter Elements `a`, `b`, `c` in this case. This is what I came up with:

```
let stepsCopy = [...stepsData];
let steps = [...stepsData].filter((step, index) => {
      return stepsCopy.filter((s, i) => {
             return  step.layout.lg.y < s.layout.lg.y;
      });
});
```

However, a `console.log(steps)` reveals that there are always the same elements (every element) in `steps` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h). What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE "not running" exampe

```js
let stepsData = [
  {"name": "a", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "b", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "c", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "d", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "e", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "f", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},
  {"name": "g", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},
  {"name": "h", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}}
]


let stepsCopy = [...stepsData];

let steps = [...stepsData].filter((step, index) => {
   return stepsCopy.filter((s, i) => {
        return  step.layout.lg.y < s.layout.lg.y
    })
});

console.log(steps);
```

Comment: Please create a working snippet that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Do you want `[[a,b,c],[d,e],[f,g,h]]`? I'm not sure what you mean, but newlines are meaningless in array literals. You also missing commas between the lists/elements.

Comment: What is stepsData? Give code that people can run.

Comment: I only want the lowest level elements so in this case `[a,b,c]`

Comment: Added an example above. @epascarello

Comment: You can't do what you want with filter, it is going to have to be done differently.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your evaluation. Can you give you me an example how it has to been solved.

Comment: @Andy like mentioned in the question above. I only want to keep the elemens `[a,b,c]`.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. It would be nice to get feedback why I got a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is not going to do the job efficiently since you are looping like crazy. There is only a need for a single loop where you keep a collection of the min items.

So the idea behind this is one loop. Loop over the array and check to see if the value is smaller or equal. If it is smaller, reset and start collecting at the index. If it is same, just append it to the list you have. If bigger ignore it.

```js
let stepsData = [
  {"name": "f", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},  //moved higher values to make sure logic works
  {"name": "a", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "b", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "c", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "d", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "e", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "g", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},
  {"name": "h", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}}
]
let stepsCopy = [...stepsData]
let minItems = stepsCopy.reduce((coll, itm) => {  //reduce the collection down to the min y values
  if (!coll.length || coll[0].layout.lg.y === itm.layout.lg.y) {  // if empty or the y's match, add to collection
    coll.push(itm)  // add item to the collection
  } else if (coll[0].layout.lg.y > itm.layout.lg.y) {  // if we find a smaller y in the set, start using that
    coll.length = 0  // reset the collection
    coll.push(itm)   // add the item
    // or instead of keeping same array you can do: return [itm]
  } // else ignore it since it is greater that the min
  return coll  // return the collection for reduce
}, []);
console.log(minItems)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm.

Comment: @Felix Either answer will work, I just made a comment on the other one to remove one loop that is not necessary. I do not know what one would preform better on larger datasets. But for your test data here, it does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

You have two logical steps:

1. Find out what the lowest value is
2. Filter the array to only include elements with that value

I would solve the problem in those two steps:

```js
let stepsData = [
  {"name": "a", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "b", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "c", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 0}}},
  {"name": "d", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "e", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 1}}},
  {"name": "f", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},
  {"name": "g", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}},
  {"name": "h", "layout": {"lg": {"y": 2}}}
]

const lowestStep = stepsData.reduce((prev, step) => 
  Math.min(prev, step.layout.lg.y), Infinity);

const filteredSteps = stepsData.filter(step => 
  step.layout.lg.y === lowestStep);

console.log(filteredSteps);
```

Comment: Damn, I like your solution much better than mine! +1!

Comment: Why map and reduce, pretty much one wasted step. Just do reduce. `const lowestStep = stepsData.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.min(prev, curr.layout.lg.y), Infinity);`

Comment: @epascarello I thought it would be cleaner like that, but you convinced me :)